# How to fix 'ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to write a code that should get inputs like below:

```
4
n hgh hjhgj jhh
1
jghj
3
```

code should get an integer n and after that get n'th strings.

```py
i =0
A=[[],[],[]]
while i < 3:
    j=0
    n=int(input())
    while j<n:
        A[i].append((input()))
        j+=1     
    i+=1
```

I expect it runs but has an Error like this:
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'hj jhg hj'
I can't understand this problem because n is an integer and A has strings and they have nothing to do with each other! Please help why it happen, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You are giving your inputs incorrectly, your code expects you to give the strings in different inputs, not in one line. To make sure what the input is asking, you could give a text to `input` so it shows in console:

```
i =0
A=[[],[],[]]
while i < 3:
    j=0
    n=int(input("n: "))
    while j<n:
        A[i].append((input("> ")))
        j+=1     
    i+=1
print(A)
```

This gives:

```
n: 4
> n
> hgh
> hjhgj
> jhh
n: 1
> jghj
n: 3
> a
> b
> c
[['n', 'hgh', 'hjhgj', 'jhh'], ['jghj'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
```

Also, when you know how many times your loop is going to iterate, instead of using `while` you could do `for`, kinda like this:

```
A = []
for i in range(3):
    n = int(input("n: "))
    temp = []
    for j in range(n):
        temp.append(input("> "))
    A.append(temp)
print(A)
```

It gives you the same result ;)

---

EDIT:

Following assumption from @kabanus, if you actually want that kind of input you need to split the given string:

```
A = []
for i in range(3):
    n = int(input("n: "))
    while True:
        words = input("> ").split()
        if len(words) == n:
          break
        print(f"You gave {len(words)} words, you must give {n} words! Try again.")
    A.append(words)
print(A)
```

This gives:

```
n: 4
> n hgh hjhgj jhh
n: 1
> jghj
n: 3
> a b c
[['n', 'hgh', 'hjhgj', 'jhh'], ['jghj'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
```

Added a `while` loop to keep asking and a little message if the incorrect number of words is given.

Comment: Upvoted for the fake shell suggestion, but I would add that OP probably wants to use split on their original input rather than change the way they input - possible with a length check.

Comment: @kabanus Probably, added a solution for the case, thanks for the advice ;)